# What does "oblong and wide like several sports fields and bordering the forest" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "oblong and wide
like several sports fields and bordering the forest" means in the following sentences:

> ‘Isn’t this house something?’ you said as we put down our things and
> unpacked. ‘It’s practically a castle.’
>
> I nodded. I wanted to be alone, to have the place all to myself, to
> take everything in. There was a view over the garden – a park, really
> – **oblong and wide like several sports fields and bordering the
> forest**. I stood and watched the last specks of light dissolve above
> it, forgetting myself, until the darkness outside was complete and I
> could see my face in the window. I turned back to the room. It was
> large, probably as big as *Pani* Kolecka’s little flat. There were two
> single beds, heavy and gleaming, separated by a nightstand with a
> porcelain lamp. A door led to a large bathroom with a bathtub. I
> turned on the tap, enjoyed the savage rumble of the water filling the
> tub. Steam rose from it. I undressed and got in, leaving the door open
> to see what I could of the park. The water was too hot, scalding
> almost, but it embraced me. I lay there for a long time, feeling my
> skin prickle from the heat, feeling droplets of sweat form on my
> forehead, letting my mind wander. After a while my eyes closed all by
> themselves.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 6](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842_51.html)

In this novel which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he decided to spend some days at the country house of Hania's family with his lover Janusz, Hania's brother Maksio, and Maksio's girlfriend Agata. So they (the five of them) arrived at the country house.

In this part, I wonder what the underlined expression means. Does it mean that the park was a narrow square, which was wide, like several sports fields attached to each other...? And that the park was situated right next to the forest?